# Rstudioでplot paneにプロットできない問題

Tags: r

RとRubyによるデータ解析入門という本のサンプルコードにて、

plotがpdfでは保存されているのですが、Rstudioの右下にあるplot paneでは表示できません。

たとえば実装例4-9などです。該当コードのサンプルリポジトリは
https://github.com/setoyama60jp/everyday/tree/master/Chapter4
にあります。

なぜ右下にあるplot paneには表示されないのでしょうか？
また、どうすれば表示されるようになりますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いちど`pdf()`で出力先を変えた後は、`dev.off()`でその出力先を閉じるまでそのPDFファイルに出力されつづけます。

`dev.off()`を何度か実行するか、Session > Restart R(Ctrl+Shift+F10)でRのセッションを再起動してみても同じでしょうか？（RStudioは、アプリケーションを閉じてもセッションが保存されるので、明示的にセッションを再起動する必要があります。設定にもよりますけど）

Comment: Session > Restart R(Ctrl+Shift+F10)でRのセッションを再起動 で出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

Rではグラフの出力先を変更することが出来ます。
コード内にあるpdf()の部分を実行せずにプロットすれば、Rstudioの右下に表示されると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
たとえば、https://github.com/setoyama60jp/everyday/blob/master/Chapter4/example4-5.r
の、
3行目の `pdf("figure4-2.pdf")`を削除して、
左上の画面の中の、右上にあるSourceボタンを押しても、plotが右下に表示されないのですが、なぜでしょうか？

Comment: `print()`で囲んでみましたが、表示されません。

Answer (score 0):

※ スクリーンショットを載せます

以下の様に `print()` で囲んで実行します。

**example4-5.r**

```r
##pdf("figure4-2.pdf")
         :
print(ggplot(data = df) + scale_shape_manual(name="Type", values=c(2,3,4)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(x = population, y = mean)) +
  geom_point(aes(x  = population, y = mean, shape = "mean")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = population, y = median)) +
  geom_point(aes(x  = population, y = median, shape = "median")) +  
  geom_smooth(aes(x = population, y = max)) +
  geom_point(aes(x  = population, y = max, shape = "max")) +
  scale_y_continuous("queue size") +
  scale_x_continuous("population"))
```

もしくは、`ggplot` の結果を変数にバインドして `print()` か `plot()` を実行します。

```r
plt <- ggplot(data = df) + ...
print(plt) ## or plot(plt)
```

**Screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

[image: R Studio Global options]

R StudioのGlobal Options内にある，R Markdownを選んで，Show output inline for ...のチェックを外せば良いのではないでしょうか？